# Search string like Father\'s Day in MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have a column contain string  Father\'s Day If search only word father query show the result Father\'s Day 
but if enter string 
Father\'s Day
Father''s Day

no result display

my query is

```
select * from temp where title like '%Father's%' datatype = 0

select * from temp where title like '%Father''s%' datatype = 0

select * from temp where title like '%Father\'s%' datatype = 0
```

Comment: From the top of my head, try '%Father\\\'s%'. \ is escape character, so it does not end up in your query, unless you have two of them. So \\ becomes \, and \' becomes '

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape special characters,

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);
```

Using PDO way:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  `temp` WHERE  `title` LIKE ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute()
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: but in database this string is store Father\'s Day

Comment: It should not. Use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to save your value as `Father's Day`.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries

1. you close a quote after Father and break your query
2. Same issue
3. You can't escape `'` inside `LIKE` pattern (only `%` and `_` are escaped)

Correct query, I believe, but I didn't check, should be:

```
select * from temp where title like "%Father's%" AND datatype = 0
```

Comment: Database show error message #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'datatype = 0 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: I don't seee a LIMIT in your question post. Post the whole thing to tell what's wrong with tour code. And `php` code forming the query might be helpful.

Comment: Hold on - what is that `datatype = 0`? There should be AND between the Father-string and the datatype condition.

Comment: So, do you have this backslash in the database or not? Could you post `SELECT * FROM \`table\` WHERE id = \`id\`` ?

Comment: Father\'s Day this string in database my requirement is to search whole string

Answer (score 0):

Use this this will work sure:

```
select * from temp where title like "%Father\\'s%" datatype = 0;
```

This will work.

And for you knowledge I want to suggest you that when ever you insert that in database then always use [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function to avoid the slash.

Comment: Database show this message MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0024 sec )

Comment: why are you searching with `"%Father\\'s%"`? try with "%Father%" and then check.

Comment: my requirement is searching whole word Father\'s Day

Comment: @UMAIRALI I want to know that in the column of database is there only "Father\'s Day" text or it has much more.

Comment: @UMAIRALI If you are finding the column that has only this text then use `title = "Father\\\'s"`. this will work sure.